# get query count in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM   TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE  T1.........
```

How can I retrieve the count of rows returned by the query excluding the top 100.
I want to return the 100 records back as well as the total count of records affected.
Is there a simpler way to do it rather than writing the whole query again without the top keyword and including count?
eg:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS TableCount
FROM   TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE  T1.........
```

Comment: when you are taking top n records, you already know the no of records, why do you need the count?

Comment: My guess is: he needs the amount of rows of the whole table (ie. for pagination).

Comment: yes, i want to display the count as well so that the user knows about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using COUNT(1) OVER() You'll get the no of records in your table in Total_Count column.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *, COUNT(1) OVER() as 'Total_Count'
FROM   TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE  T1.........
```